# How to reactivate the accounting engine in odoo 11 or 12?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

recently i install odoo 11 and the odoo 12 latest version , i have some custom module based on "account_accountent" module, so when i do some search i found this article :

[Are Accounting Features Removed](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/groups/community-59/community-32621447) (click link to see all details)

(a part of the article)
[image]

so the question here how can i reactivate the feature "account_accountent" in one XML record ?

please any one know how to do it ?

here it's my custom module who depends on "account_acountent" manifest file

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On your `__manifest__.py` file change `'account_accountant'` to `'account'` so the module may be loaded.

Then, on the web interface:

1. Enter debug mode
2. Go to Settings / Users, select one user to edit
3. On the "Application Accesses" section make sure it has "Billing Manager" to the right of "Accounting & Finance"
4. On the "Technical Settings" section make sure it has "Show Full Accounting Features" checked.
5. Save and reload bypassing your cache (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)

If you succeed, when logged in as that user you should see under Invoicing / Configuration / Accounting the following menus: Chart of Accounts, Taxes, Fiscal Positions, Bank Accounts and Journals.